# checkbox doesn't send any data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

world! I have simplest form of questionnaire (making it as a template for a future project) that contains text input, radio and checkboxes. I cannot figure out how do I make it work. Can anyone please have a look at my code and spot any problems in code? Also any recommendations on enhancing are welcomed.

```
<?php
if(isset ($_POST['submit'])){

    $con = mysql_connect ("localhost", "*********","*********");
    if (!$con){
        die ("can not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("dastiche_questionnaire",$con);
    $offers = "None";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO questionnaire 
             (fname,sex,age) 
            VALUES 
             ('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[sex]','$_POST[age]')";


    $chkbox = array('kiosk', 'tradecenter', 'bookstore');
    $wherebuycard = $_POST['wherebuycard'];
    $values = array();
    foreach($chkbox as $selection ){
        if(in_array($selection, $wherebuycard)){
            $values[ $selection ] = 1;
        }
        else
        { 
            $values[ $selection ] = 0;
        }
     } // end of foreach.

     $sql = "INSERT INTO questionnaire (wherebuycard)
             VALUES 
             ({$values['kiosk']}, {$values['tradecenter']}, 
              {$values['bookstore']})";


     mysql_query($sql,$con);

     mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

In the mysql database I have table with four columns named fname, sex, age, wherebuycard. "fname" is simple text input, "sex" is radio, "age" is dropdown and "wherebuycard" is checkbox. PHP shows no errors, but in mysql database there is no signs of data registration.

one clue: if I delete this portion of code:

```
$chkbox = array('kiosk', 'tradecenter', 'bookstore');
$wherebuycard = $_POST['wherebuycard'];
    $values = array();
    foreach($chkbox as $selection ){
        if(in_array($selection, $wherebuycard)){
            $values[ $selection ] = 1;
            }
        else
            { $values[ $selection ] = 0;
            }
    } // end of foreach.

$sql = "INSERT INTO questionnaire (wherebuycard)
          VALUES ({$values['kiosk']}, {$values['tradecenter']}, {$values['bookstore']})";
```

Then everything works (mysql receives data) except checkboxes.

Html bit:

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="wherebuycard[]" value="kiosk"> kiosk</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="wherebuycard[]" value="tradecenter"> trade center</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="wherebuycard[]" value="bookstore"> book store</p>
```

Comment: You want multiple `wherebuycard` in a record or multiple record?

Comment: From what I can see, you are creating a `$sql = '-QUERY HERE-';`  for your fname, sex, age and so on, but you don't execute it, you simply overwrite your existing `$sql` variable with a new query (the one with wherebuycard), so instead of two queries being executed, you only have 1 - oh and mysql is deprecated, you should use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Also in the second query you are trying to place 3 fields into one. That wont work. Step back, re-evaluate what you are trying to do, and then _start again_

Comment: As you are obviously just starting out with coding/PHP, take @Epodax advice and throw this code away and start again using the MYSQLI or PDO extensions. It will save you time in the long run

Comment: ok, so what I have done for now (using RiggsFolly's advices) I have created additional 2 columns and assigned kiosk, tradecented, bookstore to them. I also made all code before "INSERT" and that worked. checked items in html, returned as 1 or 0 in mysql database. Now what I dont understand is the MYSQLI extentions. Whats should I do?

Comment: I am afraid you just have to look for tutorials [google is your friend](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+mysqli+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=_q-wVZuJKca9UeD7n5gE) and read the [PHP mysqli_ manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and the [PHP PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)